# Realtime Updates: subscribing to notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, real-time-updates

Could anyone point me in the best direction to "subscribe" to notifications for a user? I tried playing around with the realtime updates API but apparently Facebook blocks subscribing to notifications.

I get an error:

`Error
Couldn't save 'user': Application cannot subscribe to notifications`

when I try to setup realtime updates for my app. If realtime updates isn't a possibility, would the only other way be for my server to poll Facebook to see if anything has changed for the user?

I feel like it should be really easy for Facebook to just enable subscribing to notification fields for the User object...

Comment: Also, if I subscribe to "friends" instead of "friend_requests", would that only be triggered if a friend request is accepted and a friend is added?

Comment: Facebook updated their Realtime docs a few weeks ago, they may be of some help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/managing-realtime-update-subscriptions/

Comment: @Antonelli it looks like I have to poll /me/notifications to get notifications. Their realtime API doesn't support subscribing to notifications.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having problems with this, facebook lists everything you can subscribe to at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#subscribefields

However they list three things you cannot subscribe to (for the user object), these are: friend_request, threads, notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, Realtime update means "user updates a field" like name, age, gender etc...